Finding Romanian birth certificate from 1957
Just a shot in the dark:
I am trying to find my mother's birth certificate from Bucharest. I don't know much about her, just her name, birthday and possibly her last name. She didn't have a middle name. She also had a nickname that she went by, but that probably wouldn't matter. She was born in December 15th 1957
I am and was born in the United States.
She met my father in Syria on business and they married (I think) in Romania either in 1980 or 1981.
My parents divorced in 1997. Many sad and traumatic things happened that I won't go into unnecessary detail about, but I mention them because that's why I can't ask my dad because his memory is very erratic and he he doesn't remember much of anything. I know he had relatives that I have never personally met or had a relationship with. She had a mother she didn't like, and her father was apparently a very bad person.
She was one of the most secretive people I have ever met.
I do NOT under any circumstances want to be reunited with her if she is still alive. I'm just trying to learn more about who I am and my background and my DNA. I think she returned to Romania if she is still alive.

You could go to: https://www.thefhguide.com/project-9-romania.html,  Otherwise, you could go to the FamilySearch Wiki for Romania: https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/index.php?search=bucharest&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1&ns12=1&ns14=1&ns3100=1

As has been commented elsewhere, this "user" appears to be posting AI-generated content.
